# backbone jquery-ui dialog buttons external function

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js, dialog

For a jquery-ui dialog inside a render function, can I have buttons that point to another function and not inline it?

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  submit: function(event) { /* foo */ },
  buttons: [{
    'text' : 'SUBMIT',
    'click' : this.submit  // <== like this
  }],

  render: function() {
    this.$el.append("I'm a dialog with a button").dialog({ buttons: this.buttons });
    return this;
  }
});
```

I ran the above code as is, and it seems like the engine can't find `submit`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined jquery-ui.js:10018  
$.widget._createButtons.$.each.props.click jquery-ui.js:10018 
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle jquery-1.9.1.js:2750
```

Comment: A little background on this question: I ran the above code as is, and seems like the engine cant find submit: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined jquery-ui.js:10018
$.widget._createButtons.$.each.props.click jquery-ui.js:10018
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle jquery-1.9.1.js:2750

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `buttons` array is interpreted when you declare your view and at that point `this` is set to the root object  (probably `window`). You can demonstrate this behavior by assigning something to `window.submit`. For example,

```
window.submit = function() {
    console.log('window submit');
}
```

is triggered when you click on your button. See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/AmRkp/ for a demo.

A solution to your problem would be to use your definition as a template to build a custom array of buttons for each instance. Something like this :

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    submit: function(event) {
        console.log(this, 'submit');
    },
    buttons: [{
        'text' : 'SUBMIT',
        'click' : 'submit'
    }],

    render: function() {
        var mybuttons;

        //extract the buttons from an array or function,
        mybuttons = _.result(this, 'buttons');

        //build the array
        mybuttons = _.map(mybuttons, function(obj) { 
            // for each object describing a button

            //create a clone to avoid problems
            obj = _.clone(obj); 
            //set the callback, bound to the view
            obj.click = _.bind(this[obj.click], this);  
            return obj;
        }, this);

        this.$el.append("I'm a dialog with a button").dialog({
            buttons: mybuttons
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/AmRkp/3/ to play with

Comment: Cool, thanks! Like that I can even move the map call to outside the render function!